# Another third party directing developers to Stack Overflow for tech support and more

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577173/enhancement-request-for-wattpad-story-search-api-add-category-ranking?noredirect=1#comment49268879_30577173) a user has come to Stack Overflow and posted a feature request in the mistaken belief that Stack Overflow is some sort of general communication channel for the company concerned. Looking at [their developer page](http://developer.wattpad.com) I can see how confusion might arise, as they list Stack Overflow along with their Twitter account under the heading:

> Community
>
> Connect with the Wattpad developer community to stay informed, receive support, and participate in events.

In this particular case I've explained to the user in question that feature requests to a third party developer are off-topic for Stack Overflow, but I can see this problem recurring in the future unless the third party company clarifies their web site in order to make it clear that Stack Overflow isn't a general communication forum for their product.

Comment: They haven't stated feature requests anywhere in there but yes contacting them to make it clear what kind of support can be expected on SO would be a good idea so their customers know exactly where to ask what.

Comment: Programmers have questions about an api isn't exactly unusual.  It is not a 3rd party if you write a program to target a specific api.  The only mistake he made was using a useless meta tag, [api] is not a good tag.  And somewhat inevitably, the engine selected you to look at it, you've answered questions tagged with [api] before.  Technically, what you *should* have done is edit those questions and remove the tag.  It is not too late.

Comment: @HansPassant: he's not asking a question though - he is actually making a *feature request* to the developers of the third party product in question (Wattpad) - the library is proprietary, it seems, so no one on StackOverflow is going to be able to address this request other than the developers. I don't see how this could possibly be on-topic for StackOverflow ? (Obviously questions about how to *use* the API might well be on-topic.)

Comment: Oh, right, agreed.

Comment: In relation to the tag in question. Its tag-wiki sounds more like an advertisement and does not give any information about the product. I have no clue whatsoever what it is after reading it. Maybe someone who does might write something useful?

Comment: They also misused the SO trademark, it should be 'Stack Overflow', not 'Stackoverflow'.

Comment: What are the obstacles to let other companies/organizations deploy the core SO technology on their servers? Then,  support requests for new features on a company's products won't be bad at all.

Comment: @RSahu The fact the SE engine needs a pretty fast system to run- I know that the SO database server (only runs SQL Server 2012, I *think*) alone has 192GB RAM and 24 cores, and that doesn't even factor in the web server (SO has an entire database server all to itself, the other SE sites share the others).

Would a business really be willing to splash out the money for the hardware & maintenance cost? Then we come to the licencing of the SE engine, which if the SE team wanted to, would cost a *huge* amount of money.

Comment: @cybermonkey You don't need a beefy machine to run a small site. Our hardware helps us support Stack Overflow's scale (with a ton of headroom). Most people running a Q&A platform (ours or similar) would not even come close to having the same hardware requirements.

Comment: @AnnaLear That's true, I suppose it all depends on the traffic of the business' current Q&A platform/forum, if they already have one.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is now [a page addressing this situation in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support), primarily addressed to the third-party themselves.

I think an appropriate action in cases like this is to leave a comment on the off-topic / low quality question *clearly linking to that official page*. Ideally, this serves multiple purposes:

- The person asking the question will understand that it is the company that is being criticized for sending them here, not them for following.
- If they succeed in finding an alternative means of contact, they may become our advocate, pointing back to the guidelines.
- If the company is in fact actively monitoring the tag, they will see the comment themselves, and hopefully clarify their links.

If a large or sustained influx of poor questions comes from a particular source, then a more official contact might be necessary.

Answer (score 26):

There are *three* total questions on the tag in question. In all honesty I think it's a wasted effort to contact every single company that does this.

When/if it becomes a problem for a specific tag (that is, we get more than a single off topic question on it - let's say 10) then the site should be contacted.

I'm not saying it's a bad thing that you opened a meta issue for this - but 35 people viewing this and the whole discussion all over doesn't seem particularly worth it given there is only 1 misbehaving question and 3 total questions on the tag.

That said - I pinged their head of product (he answered one of the questions on the tag), so they'll see it next time they visit Stack Overflow.

Comment: You're probably right, so long as Wattpad does not become the next Facebook or Twitter, at which point we might need to re-visit this. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I understand why it's been put on hold. As a note - we're in very early stages of our API, but we absolutely do plan on providing a forum for support ourselves in the future.

Comment: @tarunsachdeva Thanks for recognizing this. :)

Answer (score 4):

A response from the perspective of a product owner. In the past I encouraged people to use SO for questions about the standard interfaces that our product supports, and discouraged them from using it for product-specific questions. But that distinction really doesn't work well; firstly people aren't always sure about what's standard and what's product-specific, secondly it's a blurry line anyway because you always have cases that end up being a discussion about whether the product implements the standard correctly. So our position is now that we're happy for people to ask product-specific questions on SO, and it has a couple of benefits: firstly many of them are answered by other users before we even get to see them, secondly we're under no contractual or moral obligation to follow it through to a successful resolution. The main disadvantage is that it's not on our tracking system, which is only really a problem if there's actually a product bug being reported. But we still point people primarily to our own product support site.

As for feature requests (getting back to the question...) the boundaries are very fuzzy. A "how do I do X" question very easily blends into a "please could you provide a way of doing X" request. If you allow one and not the other, you're in danger of blocking people whose only offence is to phrase their question in the wrong way - something for which StackOverflow has a notorious reputation.

Comment: To get blocked, someone has to _persistently_ do the wrong thing. If someone keeps posting feature requests for some company's products as StackOverflow questions even after being told not to do that and pointed to the help and getting his questions closed and downvoted, then yes, he'll get blocked. And why _shouldn't_ he get blocked?

Comment: I think the important thing to make clear to users is that *they are asking a question on Stack Overflow*. The rules of Stack Overflow come first and foremost, and only within those does your policy have any effect. For instance, saying "we don't have an official support forum, but we actively monitor Stack Overflow" sets a better expectation than "Stack Overflow is our official support forum". You wouldn't expect users to file a feature request for Microsoft Windows on SO, so other third-party products are no different.