# More actively discourage third-party product support on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, flags, product-support

[Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product) are some pretty tight guidelines for product vendors that outsource their support to Stack Overflow. And vendors are [not encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project/13282#13282) to do this too easily. All is well and good.

But even for a seasoned Stack Overflow contributor like me it's impossible to know all products that use this support model. So what frequently happens is:

- User `X` asks a clearly support-related question about ProductA.
- I vote to close this question, indicating that it belongs on the product's support forum.
- `X` responds in a frustrated manner that he/she feels shuttled from pillar to post because the product's site tells them to post on Stack Overflow.
- I admit I didn't know that ProductA referred to Stack Overflow for support and (may) retract my close vote.

That's a lot of clutter and uselessly spent energy!

Just one example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778941/eclipse-sonar-analyse-crashes). You see, by the way, that the OP even thought he was contacting product support directly here. ("Did *you* introduce a new bug...", "you french guys...").

In this case, in my opinion the product vendor, SonarQube, did [a very poor job](http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/)<sup>1</sup> in instructing their users when and how to resort to Stack Overflow. And they clearly don't follow up sufficiently on questions in their tag (only an edit!). But that's beyond SO's control. *Any* product vendor can refer to SO in this poor (or even poorer) manner and lean back.

But there's more to it. Users typically won't read even the best and concise guidelines on product sites. They see "Stack Overflow" and there they go. So what we get is a lot of questions that can't even be answered here, only by the product developers themselves if they happen to be around. For instance -

- Why is this feature implemented this way?
- When do you expect to release version x.y?
- I have this feature request....

These questions are totally irrelevant on Stack Overflow (in the past they would go down as "too localized").

So I would like to actively discourage this support model in some way. I know that this is hard to realize. Maybe there should be a specific flag for it. Is SO even capable (in term of human resources) of contacting offenders?

---

<sup>1</sup>Doesn't apply any more. [They changed their support model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296893/more-actively-discourage-product-support-at-stack-overflow#comment208444_296943).

Comment: Never retract your close vote just because the OP was given incorrect advice by a third party.

Comment: Just saying because your narrative suggested you routinely do that :) Re a specific flag, the way this has worked so far was that people would complain on Meta about specific companies. I don't think a flag can improve much on that, ultimately it's up to SO staff whether they contact the company or not. Not sure whether that has happened in the case of Paypal for eaxmple

Comment: That one question may possibly be improved by changing the first paragraph - the "you" complaint.

Comment: What's the reason for discouraging this? Most vendor support forums are absolutely terrible; as a user I'd rather use SO (and contribute both ways, not be a help-vampire of course).  And in fact SO often provides better answers .

Comment: @MattMcNabb - It's fine to ask *programming* questions here, it's not OK to ask *customer support* questions here. This is OK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821923/paypal-return-url-is-giving-blank-array but this isn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362813/sorry-something-went-wrong-please-try-again-later-when-trying-to-upgrade-pay

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for clearing that up. Agree that the 2nd one isn't appropriate

Comment: Oh, no, I didn't read it as anything like that!

Comment: StackOverflow isn't here to hold the vendor's hand, nor should it IMO. It is the vendors responsibility to look after their clients. StackOverflow should only be concerned with whether or not a question is suitable for StackOverflow

Comment: @Sayse I couldn't agree more. But how do we set the fences? More and more vendors discover SO as their cheap outsourcing site.

Comment: @GertArnold - StackOverflow is the one who is in control here. We set the fences by continuing to deter bad questions, eventually those from the company would see the communities feedback on their tag (I would hope) and need to consider how to adapt their approach. I suppose it could be nice if there was something written about "how to use SO for your support" to be emailed out to the offenders but then there may already be.

Comment: @Sayse An SO-written "How to outsource support to SO" is a great idea. Do it before someone else does and get it right.

Comment: @Sayse - Personally I feel "eventually those from the company would see the communities feedback on their tag" is a bit *reactive*, while a more *proactive* approach is needed to **prevent** these things from happening in the first place.

Comment: @nwp Tim Post agreed, and wrote one several months ago. See my answer below for the link.

Comment: @BillyNate - It is reactive for the outsourcing company, but proactive for the maintenance of stack overflow (again, all that we should be concerned about). It becomes reactive for SO only when an out reach is needed in which case I don't think we can ever fully prevent. (If we could, then we would surely have found out how to stop bad questions too as a by product, right?)

Comment: All the responses to this issue seem to be about the vendor. Although the vendor is the "source" of the problem, the OP is the one confused. Why not try to educate the OP, starting by telling the OP that SO is **not** an official support forum, but an independant Q&A website. Helping OP to understand the context and maybe even rephrase the question (when applicable) could just remove (part of) the frustration.

Comment: @BillyNate There are more OPs than vendors, and it is easier to educate one vendor than the tens, hundreds, or thousands of people who use their product or will in the future. The mathematics of it show that proactive effort is most efficiently applied to the vendor.

Comment: For this particular case, leewangzhong pointed out in [a comment on the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778941/eclipse-sonar-analyse-crashes#comment49728880_30778941) that the OP tried posting this bug report elsewhere, but a SonarQube representative specifically directed him to post on StackOverflow instead. [I've replied](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/fgcBCMfGPnk/WhJcsd9jMhgJ) on that thread, directing the SonarQube representative to StackOverflow's official policy on this matter.

Comment: @Chris Baker - I never said the vendor should not be contacted or anything. I only said the OP should be helped to better understand where (s)he is asking the question.

Comment: Nope.  Questions are judged individually on their own merits.  It doesn't matter if the asker was referred by a vendor, or if they came here on their own because they think SO is better than the official support, or because official support gave them bad advice.  And it doesn't necessarily matter that they want support regarding a third-party product (particularly if it's widely used in the programming context).  Either their question is a good one, or it isn't.  The rest is immaterial.

Comment: @aroth Third parties opening the gates to crappy off-topic questions that we all have to judge on their own merits (or lack thereof) is all but immaterial. Bad-quality questions is a very big issue.

Comment: Well, looks like SonorQube updated the wording on their [get support page](http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/). It's a bit better now, in that it no longer says that bug reports should be posted on SO. See [the mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sonarqube/fgcBCMfGPnk/lSLyLlEAs0kJ) on this for more details.

Comment: So, they kind of went in a different direction... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow SO now supports product support!

Comment: @TravisJ Looks like a viable initiative to ensure that product support is really backed by a committed team. It's worth the try I guess.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is already an official policy on this, addressed to the company in question, in the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

It explicitly covers your three examples of questions that shouldn't be asked here, and where *the third-party* should direct users instead:

- I have an idea/request -- file an issue (on your own site)
- Why do you? -- your own community (developer forum etc)
- When will you? -- your own community

There's only really a need for staff to get involved if the company involved *refuses* to change their wording. The first thing to do would be for someone (i.e. you!) to send them a link to that policy, and ask them politely to tweak the wording. Remember to **assume good faith** - they probably just didn't spend long enough drafting the text, and didn't mean any harm.

See also [my previous answer on the subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295891/157957).

Comment: [As I did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778941/eclipse-sonar-analyse-crashes#comment49670004_30778941). It annoys me though that it seems to be the only thing we can do. But maybe if more people start doing this eventually "the world" will get the message.

Comment: The world would be a better place if everyone is more like IMSoP: Meaning no harm and assuming good faith all the time.

A policy on what to do with a *third-party* that does not listen (even after a lot of good faith) would not be unwelcome though.

Comment: I tried Googling what IMSoP was, came to the conclusion it must be "International Medical Society of Paraplegia" before realizing the answer is by @IMSoP. :(

Comment: Any ideas on how we could do something more pro-actively? Just as most users hardly ever bother to read the help center, it may never occur to third parties to read instructions on how to guide their users to SO. Somehow it should become common knowledge that vendors shouldn't take this lightly.

Comment: @GertArnold I can think of ways of pro-actively warning *users*, such as setting tag pop-up messages for tags where we know there are unresolved issues (e.g. "Please be aware that this site is not affiliated with company X..."). But that doesn't get to the heart of the matter, which is the *vendors* giving wrong guidance in the first place. Unfortunately, inbound links are fundamentally not something which can be controlled on the web; blame Tim Berners-Lee ;)

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP for your answer. We (SonarSource) agree that our "Get Support" page was not clear enough so we updated it to have it aligned with SO policy detailed at http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support. I hope things are clearer now (feel free to give feedback). We've always been monitoring SO because our users started asking questions there a long time ago even though we used to have a user mailing list at that time (it was unfortunately shut down recently due to the end of the Codehaus forge which used to host open-source projects like SonarQube).

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam Much appreciated :). The Entity Framework team did a similar thing after I dropped them a line. Great when people cooperate.

Answer (score 15):

I think that unless the company has support staff active on Stack Overflow, any links to Stack Overflow’s “ask a question page” should result in a page saying that Stack Overflow is not a support site for XXX.

This can be done by Stack Overflow looking at where a user has come from before deciding what content to show and having a list of web pages we do not wish to get people from.

Comment: Are you really suggesting to scrape sites around the internet for references to SO? What a job. But even then, many links to SO will be perfectly legitimate. And I think it's hard to determine whether a company has (or still has) active SO users. Should they officially be registered as XXX employee? I appreciate your input, but I think it shows how hard it is to tackle this.

Comment: @GertArnold, No, the HTTP headers tells you where someone has come from.    Meta posts can be used to ask for a "ask them" page to be added to the "blocked" list.    If the tag is coping well with the incoming questions, there is no need to to anything.    If it is not coping then the company that has created the problem must step up!

Comment: OK, but I wonder how many people will directly arrive from a third-party's support site.

Comment: @GertArnold, it is a BIG problem for a handfull of tags.     For most tags it is not an issue.

Comment: Ex: "We see that you are arriving from xxxx.com. Please be aware that Stack Exchange is an independent community of volunteers that does *not* provide official support for any outside programs or lbrariesi. If you've been directed to this page for customer support purposes, please return to xxxx.com and inform its maintainers to this message." Dialog has to be closed to continue; certain sites can be whitelisted by request if they happen to word their links well.

Comment: Something like this could actually work I think, although in the beginning this will probably produce many many false positives.

Comment: Another possible advantage is that we could resolve this by community moderation (white-list product sites).

Comment: @GertArnold, or the system can look at close votes and down votes and lean it's self.

Comment: Accepted this as the best answer, because it's at least an effort to do something proactively. We're a long way from implementing something along these lines, I'm afraid...

Comment: And I agree with @GertArnold, I feel that this answer is very reasonnable. FYI, we (SonarSource) would have never asked our users to use SO without making sure that our dev team is actively monitoring the "sonarqube" tag => the most active users for this tag are all (except Mark O'Connor) SonarSource guys: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sonarqube/topusers.

Comment: This would come up against the "interaction algorithm" problem almost immediately (e.g. Facebook's products showing you posts with people you interact with the most meaning you get silo'd in with the same few people more and more over time). How can the support staff become active if users are not able to post questions about the product here?

Answer (score 7):

In Fall 2014, I enrolled in an edX class (CS169.1X) that recommended SO for general Ruby/Rails questions; however, for questions specific to the class, students were directed to the class StackExchange forum. Unfortunately, I cannot find the class forum, and cannot link to it for reference.

I think there should be stricter guidelines for third-party product support. By stricter, I think that products/services used by programmers are acceptable (eclipse, vim, firefox), as long as there is a developer aspect involved. But using SO as a bug support forum takes away from the Q&A quality of the site. As @Gert referenced, someone posted in the question offensive remarks targeted at the company. For another SO user to stumble on the question, it would seem like OP is venting.

As others have pointed out, this is not a perfect world, and companies will continue to reference StackOverflow -- partly because it is already free, and partly because it's already *there* (rather than making their own support forum and hosting it). I do not know if there are legal/attribution obligations on these companies, but they should only be allowed to post on SO *iff* there is a pre-existing or to-be approved tag.

Comment: The class forum you are referring to was shutdown I think http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231208/what-is-story-behind-the-edx-stackexchanges#comment841961_231238

Comment: @rene That makes sense. Why was it shut down? Did the edX partnership with SO end? The link you sent was from May 2014, and I took the class Fall 2014.

Comment: The comments are from june, 8th and I saw a comment earlier (maybe in chat) that the sites were no longer reachable. [Jaydles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231208/what-is-story-behind-the-edx-stackexchanges#comment842517_231238) comment is the most official stuff I have...

Comment: That is very strange. Being in the class, I think the sites were removed maybe to discourage "cheating". I use quotes because although the instructors allowed questions about the homework, edX may have viewed some responses/answers as violating their honor code.

Comment: I can see how there is a thin line between an asking a honest question and having someone else doing your (course) work. It requires discipline from all parties involved

Comment: Yes. I feel that if edX allows forums for its classes, it should lax its honor code. That is why I had to move my work from github to bitbucket, so others could not find it and copy.

Comment: Haha, I was once doing an online course on a rather obscure language, and very curiously, there would be a rather specific and familiar looking set of duplicate niche questions on that language coming up on SO every time an assignment deadline came up...

Answer (score -7):

People do this because it looks like there have been exceptions to this rule.

Or at least there have seemed to be.

When devs see the Facebook graph subsite that was actually just StackOverflow, they think their own venture can use StackOverflow in the same way for their support forum. Or they eventually go work for one of the companies that also did this.

It is also faster to get answers on stackoverflow than some company's neglected subsite.

This post alone is more surprising to me than anything "this site is suddenly discouraging this?" but in reality it is just certain kinds of questions that are being discouraged, which is understandable, but I think it is going to be hard to enforce that distinction

Comment: There *haven't* been exceptions to this rule.  Companies are more than welcome to point users to SO for questions about programming problems using their product, instead of using in-house customer support for those questions *that have always been on topic on SO*.  It has never been acceptable for companies to send otherwise off topic questions to SO and have them be appropriate.  Some have tried, but SE has not accepted the questions.

Comment: "Companies are more than welcome to point users to SO for questions about programming problems using their product, instead of using in-house customer support for those questions that have always been on topic on SO." @Servy we actually agree. It is the title to this question that I was commenting about

Comment: Your answer seems to be claiming that there have been cases where sites have been allowed to direct questions to SO that wouldn't normally meet the site's standards.  That has never been the case.  Some companies may have done it *despite the fact that they weren't given permission, and where the questions weren't welcomed*.

Comment: @Servy "where sites have been allowed to direct questions to SO that wouldn't normally meet the site's standards." ah, no, just using SO for developer support. Which it seemed this post was also trying to discourage, at first. I am pointing out that OTHER people don't know this distinction. One company uses SO for developer support and everyone else sees that as general support so they try it. There isn't anything obvious to these other people to deter them from trying it

Comment: So you're saying you didn't actually read the question to understand what it was really asking, and as a result answered a completely different question than what was being asked?

Comment: @Servy I didn't say that and I clarified

Comment: So then you statement that there have been exceptions to SO's rules is just wrong.  Your answer also doesn't say anything about people mistakenly thinking that they can direct inappropriate questions to SO when they can't.

Comment: @Servy alright, I edited the wording

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80594/discussion-between-cqm-and-servy).