# Tell SonarSource that SO is not a bug tracker

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

There's an interesting paragraph on [Visual Studio's SonarQube C# Code Analysis page](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/148ea243-c018-4138-9222-4f0e81270f6a):

> Report bugs on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) with the tags "sonarqube" and "c#".

Prompted by [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361584/bug-sonarcube-c-sharp-analyzer-raises-s2325-for-unit-test-methods) (now deleted).

Perhaps someone could tell them ([SonarSource](http://www.sonarsource.com/), although not quite sure who's responsible of the Visual Studio page) that Stack Overflow might not be the best place to report bugs?

Comment: The company has lots of devs actively answering questions at SO, the [sonarqube] tag is lively.  I just posted a link to this meta question in a comment to [a recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31336403/17034) by @Mithfinder, good way to let them know.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to this meta topic. I have forwarded the issue to the relevant team at SonarSource, and I agree that some topics addressed under the [sonarqube] tag have nothing to do on SO.

Comment: In fact this question not fully duplicates [the previous one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296893/more-actively-discourage-product-support-at-stack-overflow). Indeed there is no more any doubt about when asking a question on StackOverflow is suitable or not based on the [following SonarSource's guidelines](http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/). But indeed we forgot to also update the documentation page of C# Code Analysis extension for Visual Studio. We're going to fix that quickly.