# Is Chromium Extensions invitation worded correctly?

Tags: discussion, product-support

I found an interesting [invitation to continue the "discussion"](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions) at Stack Overflow:

> For additional technical questions and discussion, we recommend Stack
>   Overflow

I had understood that discussion is not the focus of the site per
[Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Related question [More actively discourage third-party product support at Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296893/more-actively-discourage-product-support-at-stack-overflow/379421?noredirect=1#comment665467_379421)

Is the invitation worded correctly?

Comment: The angst lies with the word "discussion".  If they removed "and discussion," from that paragraph, no one would have a problem with this sentence.

Comment: @Makoto Isn't https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ designed for discussion? They should've mentioned that for discussion and that would also fix the sentence.

Comment: Probably @TrooperZ, but compared to the number of people that visit the main site, the number of people that visit chat is a rounding error.  Besides, you're likely not going to enjoy the same level of constructivity in Stack Overflow chat as  you would if you set up your own chat room to do this sort of thing in.