# Answers/comments that discourage posting on SO but ask users to post on the vendor's site itself

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364192/vscode-transferring-current-tasks-json-make-command-to-makefile-extension) question on Stack Overflow. There was a comment that such question should be first asked on the vendor's website.

However, in this case, the vendor of [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), Microsoft, officially encourages users to post questions on Stack Overflow.

Evidence: See [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose) where the link for "Question" points to [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code).

In my experience, there are indeed some vendors that discourage users from cross-posting questions on their forum as well as on Stack Overflow. However, such vendors' developers non-anonymously post on Stack Overflow and they indicate that they regularly monitor questions on Stack Overflow about their product.

However, in case of Visual Studio Code, while Visual Studio Code developers may very well be posting on Stack Overflow, as far as I know, they do so anonymously (I could be wrong here.)

So, could we not please automatically ask users to post questions first on the vendors' forums? Taken to the extreme, why not post all questions on the vendors' forums themselves? What is the point of Stack Overflow then?

Comment: See [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) "How do I?" questions are fine and on-topic on Stack Overflow. Your question on the other hand also seems to say that their implementation is missing something which would be better as an issue on their site. Your question still seems on-topic though since you ask "How can this functionality be achieved via the extension?".

Comment: There are several similar questions; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296339/reach-out-to-paypal-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-overflow appears to be rather comprehensive.

Comment: Submitted an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134086

Comment: @tripleee My OP was not intended to STOP any vendor from linking to SO. I have benefitted significantly from anonymous posters here who may very well be VSCode developers. Please reconsider this stance. Anonymity provides for more numerous transactions/answers and more liquidity in any marketplace. An anonymous poster can afford to be harsher (rightfully in many instances) in telling the truth than a known developer in a vendor. Indeed possibly because of VSCode's stance, SO has indeed solved many VSCode related problems, more than the original VSCode site itself!!!

Comment: I'm not striving to stop them from linking here, but the presentation currently implies that random technical support questions are welcome here, which they are not. I'm not sure I understand most of your comment above, though. How is anonymity relevant here anyway?

Comment: @Tryer we have guidelines for how and when vendors should refer questions to SO. See [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849) | [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) | [Another third party directing developers to Stack Overflow for tech support and more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295869) | [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: There are no close votes on your question so, unless there was a close vote that was later retracted, it doesn't look like anyone was trying to actually stop you from asking your question here.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what this Meta-Q is trying to get across. Is it about the specific question or the general approach of recommending *some* questions be posted elsewhere? Why does it matter that some vendor decides what they deem appropriate for SO? How does anonymity play into this? What is even meant by anonymity here? Are the last few questions meant to be sarcasm?

Comment: This question should better ask under which circumstances it's okay to recommend posting somewhere else if the question would also be ontopic here and in which form that should happen. In the end it's the decision of the content creator where to post independent of any recommendation.

Comment: My impression is that Microsoft has a cadre of (usually somewhat illiterate and tone-deaf) support drones who have an -MSFT suffix in their user name on Stack Overflow. They want to appear to care about communities, though their true priorities are unfortunately rather obvious.

Answer (score 18):

From my experience, Microsoft is notorious for sending people to SO with off-topic questions and not caring about any feedback they get about it (see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394024/burninate-office-store-tag)).

From the SO perspective, things should be simple: judge questions on their own merit, regardless of whether the user was directed here by the vendor. If it is a good, on-topic question it stays, if it is off-topic it gets closed and eventually deleted (if things go as they should).

Comment: Microsoft has an *awful* habit of spamming links to [so] in their Documentation Githubs now (At least in the SQL Server Documentation one): [1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6875#issuecomment-929489939), [2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6874#issuecomment-929483106), [3](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6818#issuecomment-921298374)

Comment: "From the SO perspective things should be simple..." So no recommendations either way? At least I didn't find any in the list you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

So, guessing a bit as to what you are actually trying to ask here, I suppose we could offer the following general guidance:

- If you do post the same question in multiple places, be candid about it, and link between the two so that we can see the full picture.

  - Ideally, **don't.** If you have to, probably make the other question simply a forward pointer to your question on Stack Overflow, and collect all answers there.
- Stack Overflow does not have a specific policy on cross-posting on other sites, but making sure everyone who participates has access to the available information in a single place is a principle which we attempt to follow on our site, and probably a good model to extend to also cover the case you are asking about.

  - Because other sites want to be Stack Overflow when they grow up, probably prefer Stack Overflow as the central site.
  - More seriously, we believe our model works well for the topics we permit here, and see problems with more traditional approaches (e.g. mailing lists or forum-based sites); we actively strive to make the information we gather here serve future visitors, too, and try to reduce noise to a minimum. The active curation model we have, the visibility of our site in search results, and the simple, explicit, and (reasonably) uniform licensing model we apply to all posts should also be factored in to the decision.

To somewhat reiterate Stack Overflow's mission and scope:

- We are just regular users, like yourself. General technical support questions (download links, service outages, general computer troubleshooting, bug reports, feature requests, etc) are not acceptable here; we strictly focus on *programming-related* questions.
- The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) explains our policies in more detail.

For your concrete case, I don't think your question *needs* to be asked from the developers of the extension you are having trouble with, but for rather specialized support questions like this, reaching out to the official support channel is somewhat more likely to reach someone who is actually familiar with the technology and able to answer your question.

Given that you already received an answer in the cross-posted question, at this point please either delete your question on Stack Overflow, or post an answer which summarizes the information you received and links to it. The latter option vaguely implies a commitment to keep the answer on Stack Overflow up to date over time.

Comment: Bewilderingly, they closed [the issue I created](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134086) with no action.